# Modifying Existing XML Content in C#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-2.0, setattribute, selectnodes

I found some examples about this subject. Some of the examples gived a method to modify attribute with `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()`, and others gived the method to modify attribute with `someElement.SetAttribute("attribute-name", "new value");`

But I still confused that how to build the relation if I only used a `XpathNodeItterator it`?

Assumed I defined as below,

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(xmlFile);
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator it;

it = nav.Select("/Equipment/Items/SubItmes");
while (it.MoveNext())
{
   name = it.Current.GetAttribute("name ", it.Current.NamespaceURI);
   int vidFromXML = int.Parse(it.Current.GetAttribute("vid", it.Current.NamespaceURI));
   if (vidFromXML = vid)
   { 
    // How can I find the relation between it and element and node? I want to modify name attribute value. 
   }
}
```

Is there a method like `it.setAttribute(name, "newValue")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx):  "An XPathNavigator object is created from a class that implements the IXPathNavigable interface such as the XPathDocument and XmlDocument classes. **XPathNavigator objects created by XPathDocument objects are read-only** while XPathNavigator objects created by XmlDocument objects can be edited. An XPathNavigator object's read-only or editable status is determined using the CanEdit property of the XPathNavigator class."

So, first of all you have to use XmlDocument, not XPathDocument, if you want to set an attribute.

An example of how to modify XML data using an XPathNavigator using the CreateNavigator method of an XmlDocument, is shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx28tfx1.aspx).

As you'll see from the example, there is a method **SetValue** on your it.Current object.

Here's how you would do it for your code, with some slight modifications:

```
        int vid = 2;
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<Equipment><Items><SubItems  vid=\"1\" name=\"Foo\"/><SubItems vid=\"2\" name=\"Bar\"/></Items></Equipment>");
        var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

        foreach (XPathNavigator it in nav.Select("/Equipment/Items/SubItems"))
        {
            if(it.MoveToAttribute("vid", it.NamespaceURI)) {
                int vidFromXML = int.Parse(it.Value);                    
                if (vidFromXML == vid)
                {
                    // if(it.MoveToNextAttribute() ... or be more explicit like the following:

                    if (it.MoveToParent() && it.MoveToAttribute("name", it.NamespaceURI))
                    {
                        it.SetValue("Two");
                    } else {
                        throw new XmlException("The name attribute was not found.");
                    }                
                }
            } else {
                    throw new XmlException("The vid attribute was not found.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I studied the MSDN tutorial. I found the method of 'SetValue' was used to update element value, not attribute value. Can tried it but failed. I need to find a way to update attribute value.

Comment: I found your detail update now. Introduced `it.MoveToAttribute()`. I will try it now. Thank you.

Comment: There is no `var` in .NET 2.0. I can't use `int.Parse(name)` when I pass a string type value to `name`. Throw out **Input string was not in a correct format.**. How can I fix it?

Comment: In your code sample, your int was coming from the vid attribute, which I missed in my sample.  I've updated my code to reflect that.

Comment: I still think it's bizarre that Microsoft saw fit to include `GetAttribute` and `CreateAttribute` methods but not a `SetAttribute` one, given that the functionality of `SetAttribute` is helpful and can indeed be implemented using an extension method.

Comment: @Jez I agree ... I suppose it's just to try to maintain the readonly semantics ... other than that I have no idea why they would do that.

Comment: @RichardHein But it doesn't have readonly semantics - there is a `SetValue` method and a `CreateAttribute` one.

Comment: @Jez Indeed, that's true ... :) ... it really doesn't make sense then.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension method that provides a `SetAttribute` method for any `XPathNavigator`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace My.Shared.Utilities {
    public static class XmlExtensions {
        public static void SetAttribute(this XPathNavigator nav, string localName, string namespaceURI, string value) {
            if (!nav.MoveToAttribute(localName, namespaceURI)) {
                throw new XmlException("Couldn't find attribute '" + localName + "'.");
            }
            nav.SetValue(value);
            nav.MoveToParent();
        }
    }
}
```