# How do I assign innerXML value to an XPathNavigator?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

The following line of code is throwing a `System.NotSupportedException` when I try to assign a value to `InnerXml`:

```
XPathNavigator dataItem = currentXPathDoc.CreateNavigator();
dataItem.MoveToChild(XPathNodeType.Element);
dataItem.InnerXml = TemplateEvaluator.NormalizeUnicode(dataItem.InnerXml);
```

This is expected from the documentation:

```
// Exceptions:
//   System.InvalidOperationException:
//     The System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.InnerXml property cannot be set.
```

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to change the `InnerXml` of this node without full-on refactoring it to use an `XDocument` rather than `XPathNavigator`

Is this possible?  Or do I have to take the performance/consistency hit and use something else here?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the code to reproduce the issue? Or what `dataItem` is set to.

Comment: @RyanGates I did, and I think the other Ryan's answer pointed me in the right direction.  I changed it to use an XDocument rather than XPathDocument, testing it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPathNavigator objects created by XMLDocument objects can be edited. XPathNavigator objects created by an XPathDocument are read only.

There is another question on SO similar to this:

[Modifying Existing XML Content in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623211/modifying-existing-xml-content-in-c-sharp)

It also links to an article from Microsoft on how to Modify XML using an XPathNavigator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx28tfx1.aspx

Comment: this should be a comment not an Answwer

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm creating this from an `XPathDocument`, so this doesn't work for me.